# How to update existing product category from csv programmatically in Magento?

Tags: magento-1.9, product, category, database

Can anyone help me?

I have 100 product where category is blank.

**Now I want to insert new category for those products via csv programmatically.**

Comment: Why do you need to upload CSV programmatically. You can use magento's import function with sku and category to update the categories.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a script to read CSV and assign Category ID to existing products.

Load product :

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load(PRODUCT_ID);
```

Prepare Category(ies) array :

```
$categories = array(CATEGORY_ID);
//For multiple categories, use this line
$categories = array(CATEGORY_ID_1, CATEGORY_ID_2, .....  CATEGORY_ID_n);
```

Assign Category(ies) to Loaded product :

```
$product->setCategoryIds($categories);
```

Saving product :

```
$product->save();
```

**Putting all together :**

```
$allProducts = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();

foreach($allProducts as $product){
    $categories = array(CATEGORY_ID);
    //For multiple categories, use this line
    //$categories = array(CATEGORY_ID_1, CATEGORY_ID_2, .....  CATEGORY_ID_n);
    $product->setCategoryIds($categories);
    $product->save();
}
```

Comment: @Anwar feel free to accept an answer if it worked for you.

Comment: This is adding new category also, not replacing existing category

Answer (score 0):

Use below code to add category

```
$productCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();

foreach($productCollection as $product){
  $categories = array($category_id);
  $product->setCategoryIds($categories);
  $product->save();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Export all your 100 products, and in csv file under "categories" column put your categories like `Default Category/Gear,Default Category/Gear/Bags` for each product, and upload again. This will update your products and associate categories to your products.